# What variety is my Aloe?

Tags: identification, aloe

I was given this small Aloe several years ago. It basically never really grew until a few months ago. I find that it needs A LOT of water (I always thought they don't need so much).

I do not put it in the sunlight, or it seems to get burned (leaves get brown until it gets water, I managed to save it a few times haha).

May 2020 (underwatered):

[image: May 2020]

And today ; 7 months later:
[image: Front view]

[image: Side view shows it's all on one "plan" / "side"]

I'm wondering what variety it is because that's the first Aloe I see that only grows in one "plan" (all the leaves stack on the same direction, sorry English is not my first language).

That would allow me to seek better care options for it.

Update 2021: it died :'( Overwatered it it seems

Comment: After navigating through the related questions, I have come across https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/18063/28266 and that plant looks very similar, and I have come across similar problems (thin leaves, browning). [One answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/24224/28266) suggests it could be an _Aloe chinensis_, and after Googling some images it does match but only for small specimens. Maybe my plant is just very very small?

Comment: To me it seems to be the regular *Aloe vera* that is available everywhere where I live, but it still can be the one described in the referred answer. :)

Comment: @BenceKaulics my question was "is there such thing as _regular Aloe vera_"? Don't they all have a more specific name? That's what I wanted to know :)

Comment: There are about 450 species of *Aloe* and some of those 450 have several varieties. Several species have "two rows of leaves in a flat plane" like your picture. I can't identify the exact species but while it is an *Aloe* I don't think it is a variety of *Aloe vera*.

Comment: @alephzero The plant in question seems to be the same as [mine](https://imgur.com/5kXbk2K) which was growing in a flat plane for a very long time. Then I moved it and started to twist so the new leaves would reach towards the window.